# How come the following program output is 5, not 4? Could anyone explain?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I came upon a program which outputs 5. I don't know how. Please explain.

```
int main(void) {
        int t[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }, *p = t;
        p += 2;
        p += p[-1];
        printf("\n%d",*p);
        return 0;
    }
```

I expect the output to be 4.
the pointer moves from t[0] to t[2] here(p+=2;). In the next statement p+= p[-1], I believe pointer moves to t[1] whose value is 2 first and so increased by 2. So I expected output to be 4.
but the actual output is 5. Anyone, please explain?

Comment: `t[0] to t[3]` no, it's from `t[0]` to `t[2]`. `0 + 2 = 2`.

Comment: Draw the array on a piece of paper. Draw a separate box for `p`, and draw an arrow where it points. Erase and redraw the arrow as you change `p`. Then you should hopefully quite easily see which element of the array that `p[-1]` is, and what its value is.

Comment: Your description is accurate except for "I believe pointer moves to t[1]".  No, the pointer is incremented by the value in t[1], so it moves to t[4] (which you seem to get).  And the value of t[4] is 5.

Comment: pointer address changes if an integer is added or subtracted to it. why not it happens in p[-1] and only value of p[-1] is taken? I studied P[i] is taken as *(p+i).

Comment: Thank you so much, everyone! I get it now.

Comment: Check your understanding by adding `printf("%p : %p = %d\n", (void *)t, (void *)p, *p);` before the `+= 2` line, after it, and before your current `printf()`.  This will show you more of what's going on.  Adding such diagnostic output should be a reflex action when something doesn't behave as you expected.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I didn't know that before and I learned now thanks to you. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, the pointer `p` points to the beginning of the array `t`. So it should be something like

```
p--
  |
  v
------------------------------------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
------------------------------------------
```

Now by

```
p += 2
```

`p` is increment according to pointer arithmetic. So that `p` is now pointing to `3`.

```
p----------
          |
          v
------------------------------------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
------------------------------------------
```

`p[-1]` is same as `*(p-1)`. ie, the value at the address `p-1`. This value is `2`.

```
      ------ p[-1] or *(p-1)
      |
      |
------|-----------------------------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
------------------------------------------
```

After adding `2` to the current value of `p`, `p` would now be pointing to `5`.

```
p------------------
                  |
                  v
------------------------------------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
------------------------------------------
```

So, when you print the value of `*p`, `5` is output.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. I get it now. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

```
p = t; // p = &t[0]
p += 2; // p = &t[2]
p += p[-1]; // p += 2; // p = &t[4]
```

Comment: p[-1] same as *(p-1). I assume Pointer p goes back to t[1] and now p=p+ p[-1] becomes p=p+2. pointer shifts from t[1] to t[3] . May I know what mistake I did?

Comment: `p[-1]` (or `*(p-1)`) does not change the value of `p` anymore than `p[2]` (or `*(p+2)`).